# kinect install instructions for electric not working

Tags: kinect, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect

I've tried the apt-get install and the source based for electric on Ubuntu 11.10.

When I run the following command it errors out.

```
punchingpro@punchingpro:~/ros_workspace/drivers$ rosmake openni_kinect --rosdep-install
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['openni_kinect']                           
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/punchingpro/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120615-132043
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['openni_kinect'] to:
['nite', 'openni', 'openni_launch', 'openni_tracker', 'openni_camera', 'depth_image_proc']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
Failed to find rosdep nite-dev for package nite on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
Failed to find rosdep openni-dev for package openni on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
Failed to find rosdep ps-engine for package nite on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Rosdep install failed                        
punchingpro@punchingpro:~/ros_workspace/drivers$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36623/kinect-install-instructions-for-electric-not-working/) by [punching](https://answers.ros.org/users/1882/punching/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you've been following this tutorial to get your kinect up and running:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect

I briefly attempted to follow this tutorial as well, and it got me good and stuck with the same rosdep errors for Lucid.

If you're running the a recent version of ROS Electric, then you already have the open_kinect stack here: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect
Simply remove the tutorial's openni_ros folder from your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. In your specific case:

```
rm -r ~/ros_workspace/openni_ros
```

Then launch your kinect!

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0